# Convert JDom Document to SOAPMessage in Java

Tags: java

How to convert org.jdom.Document to javax.xml.soap.SOAPMessage in java?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this should work, although it's a bit clunky and won't be fast:

```
MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();

public SOAPMessage toMessage(Document jdomDocument) throws IOException, SOAPException {
   String xml = new XMLOutputter().outputString(jdomDocument);
   InputStream inputStream = new StringBufferInputStream(xml);
   return messageFactory.createMessage(null, inputStream);
}
```

This assumes that the JDOM document represents a valid SOAP message structure in it's entirety, headers and all.

Comment: StringBufferInputStream is deprecated. An updated answer would be helpful :) I do not have that yet...

Comment: new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes("UTF-8"))